# python pandas data frame replace ends of string values to another character

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

I want to replace ends of string values in one column to another character. Here, I want to convert every ends of string values to '0'. The values in 'Codes' column are string.

e.g

```
    Code    
1   11-1111
2   12-2231
3   12-1014
4   15-0117
5   16-2149
```

to

```
    Code    
1   11-1110
2   12-2230
3   12-1010
4   15-0110
5   16-2140
```

What method I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be

```
df.Code = df.Code.str[:-1] + '0'
```

You get

```
    Code
1   11-1110
2   12-2230
3   12-1010
4   15-0110
5   16-2140
```

Comment: You can't beat that solution. +1

Comment: Thank you! You made my Friday:)

Comment: Happy weekends +1